# twitter bootstrap3 behaviour in all the Browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How is datatables and liast boxes are handled in twitter bootstrap 3?

please let me know whether twitter bootstrap 3 works well with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Browser compatibility is listed on the Bootstrap homepage:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers

Regarding datatables, if you are referring to the jQuery DataTables plugin at datatables.net, there isn't an official Bootstrap 3 style for it at this time.

However, I have a blog post about some modifications I've made from the Bootstrap 2 examples (datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2) that you can try out:

http://devblog.rayonnant.net/2013/09/bootstrap-3-datatables-paging.html

I hope this helps answer your questions.